# Select img in specific div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to use `img` tags in a specific `div` for a selector.

```
$('img').click(function() {
    // something happens here 
}
```

Now all images on the site are firing the click function. But I want that only for the images in the specific div.

```
<div id="triggerimg">
    <img src="bla.jpg"/>
    <img src="bla.jpg"/>
    <img src="bla2.jpg"/>
</div>
```

There must be something like

```
$('triggerimg#img').click(function() { //... }
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/wcA7s/)***

jQuery selectors follow the same specification as css selectors for the most part, so you need to target the id, and then then select the nested image elements

```
$('#triggerimg img').click(function(){/*code*/});
```

Comment: so close, so simple! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is (`#` is the ID selector)

```
$('#triggerimg img').click(function() { //... }
```